# NSXMLParser : requesting guidance with making grouped tables from an RSS/XML feed

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, ios, uitableview, nsxmlparser

Im making a group table that is populated from an XML/RSS feed, ive managed to parse the data to the table just fine, but im stuck on how to make the table grouped?

ie, i want an events listing, and i want to organise the events in groups, using the Month for each group, how would i achieve this?

below is my XML structure, its pretty basic

```
<EventsUpcoming>

<Event id="1">
<month>July</month>
<title>Ian Moss</title>
<date>Saturday, July 1st</date>
<ticket>$35 On the door</ticket>
<description>
Ian Moss from Cold Chisel fame will be touring Australia and the only venue to secure him in Perth is the Blvd.
</description>
</Event>

<Event id="2">
<month>August</month>
<title>Cold Chisel</title>
<date>Saturday, August 3rd</date>
<ticket>$25 on the door</ticket>
<description>
From Khe San fame, Cold Chisel is back with the legendary Jimmy Barnes, dont miss out this gig. Its gonna go down in the books for sure!
</description>
</Event>

<Event id="3">
<month>September</month>
<title>Australian Crawl</title>
<date>Saturday, September 1st</date>
<ticket>Free</ticket>
<description>
They're one of Australia's most iconic band names, be sure to come down and check them out before they die.
</description>
</Event>

</EventsUpcoming>
```

If anyone knows any tutorial sites that might be helpful or just tips on how to go about doing this, thatd be much appreciated. Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[NSMutableSet](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableSet_Class/Reference/NSMutableSet.html) doesn't store the duplicate values,it only stores distinct ones.So at the time of parsing,you can use NSMutableSet to store the 'month' value of each xml element and set the number of sections in a tableview to the count of your NSMutableSet.

Comment: So are you saying, i can have multiple events under one "Month" and then just count them?